# Doesn't exist Google Play services libproject folder

Tags: android, google-play-services

I want to create an android project with Google Map Api. So I downloaded Google Play services via SDK Manager.But doesn't exist Google Play services "libproject" folder. Any help will be appreciated.

[image: SDK Manager]

Folders path and folders:

[image: Path]

[image: Folders]

Comment: Okay, but have you tried setting up Google play services to get the maps package and ran into any error? https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: I think you'll want to install the "Google Repository" package there, first

Comment: Yes, I get "The import com.google.android.gms.maps cannot be resolved" error.

Comment: Previously, didn't require  "Google Repository" package.

Comment: Did you compile the maps dependency? I assume you are using Gradle and Android Studio?

Comment: Overall, this is all you need to know about getting Google maps in your app. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/

Comment: I use Eclipse Adt Bundle.

Comment: Are you aware that as of 2016, that is no longer officially supported for Android development? You may have your reasons against Android Studio, but continuing to use Eclipse is only preventing you from quickly creating apps and finding the necessary resources to build a project

Answer (score 3):

You'll find them(take in mind that services are separated) in /extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms

1. Find library, which you need (ads for example)
2. Rename .aar to .zip
3. Unzip the file
4. Import the project into Eclipse by using New -> Project -> Android Project from Existing Source Code
5. Go to the Project's properties and set the Build Target and 'Is Library' flag
6. Go into your project properties and link library, which you created

PS 0-4 can be replaced by downloading libs here: 
https://github.com/dandar3/android-google-play-services-base