# Google Maps rev. 30 eclipse usage : google_play_services_version

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-play-services

Well, on rev.30 Google decided to split back its services from 20k methods library back into separate ones.

So now in \sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms we've got a lot of different libraries. That's super convenient!

But, after successfully installing Google Maps from sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-maps\9.0.2 from a separate .aar , my app crashes with `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment.`

After some research I've found that it happens if there is no meta-data in manifest.

I use both

```
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
 android:value="@string/google_api_key">

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
  android:value="@string/google_api_key"/>
```

(i know that I need only one of them)

but I also have to use

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and "google_play_services_version" is nonexistent in a library project of the latest rev. 30 google library. What can I do?

Keep in mind that I'm using Eclipse, if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem lies on the fact that Google has [dropped its support for Eclipse](http://www.zdnet.com/article/google-releases-android-studio-kills-off-eclipse-adt-plugin/). This looks similar to this [SO thread's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37776582/doesnt-exist-google-play-services-libproject-folder). I recommend you move to Android Studio.

Now onto the rev.30 problem. Saw this question asked in [this thread](http://cudou.com/pages/dhehgaah-there-is-no-libproject-inside-google-play-services-rev-30-in-eclipse-juno.html). The community suggested you use rev.28. Check it out as well.